# Rails RSpec Returning Nil Instead of Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a really straightforward controller action that is failing my RSpec test and I don't understand why.  I'm hoping someone can help me see where I'm making a mistake.

The actions simply gets `GroupMember` records for a given `User` with `group_member.status == "approved"`

The test is failing saying that nil is being returned instead of my expected value of GroupMember.

I know that it works because I'm looking at the view in my development environment.

```
# users_controller
def groups
  @group_member = current_user.group_members.approved   
end

# user.rb
has_many :group_members, :dependent => :destroy

# routes.rb
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'groups'     
  end
end

# group_member.rb
belongs_to :user
scope :approved, where(:status=>"approved")

# users_controller_spec.rb
describe "GET #groups" do
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    current_user = sign_in @user
    @group_member = FactoryGirl.create(:group_member, user_id: @user.id, status: "approved") 
  end

  it "assigns group member correctly" do
    get :groups 
    assigns[:group_member].should eq [@group_member]
  end

 end
```

Comment: Can you check if `sign_in @user` actually returns current_user? I would also try changing `current_user` to `@current_user`

Comment: Hi Jason, I just tried moving the current_user line into the It block, tried setting current_user to `@current_user`, and also tried changing it to get :groups, current_user: `@current_user`.  None of it worked though.

Comment: Can you show me `sign_in` method?

Comment: It's the one provided by the test helpers in the Devise gem, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.

Comment: I am not really sure what `sign_in` returns. Can you try this? Change `current_user = sign_in @user` to `sign_in @user` and `@current_user = @user`

Comment: Can you post the error message by the way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35861/discussion-between-yellowreign-and-jason-kim)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the method a lot, but my understanding from the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) is that `assigns` is a method that accepts the variable symbol as a parameter, as in `assigns(:group_member)`. It doesn't return an object that you access via `[]`, as you have done.